# Cannot RDP to CentOs 7 Azure VM

Tags: azure, centos, xrdp

I haven't been able to RDP to my newly created CentOs 7 Azure VM.

In my attempt to accomplish this I followed the steps listed here: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2015/05/02/remote-desktop-to-your-linux-azure-virtual-machine/

To summarize, I've installed GNOME Desktop, VNC Server, and xrdp. The instructions above talk about adding an endpoint, but since I'm using the Resource Manager deployment model, there's no settings or menu items where I can create one. Instead I added inbound rules to my network security group to allow traffic to ports used by xrdp and vncserver. Rdp and VNC viewer both timeout when I attempt to connect.

Additionally, I used the sudo netstat -ant command to confirm that both ports (for xrdp and vncserver) are both in the "LISTEN" state.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do your NSG (network security group) rules look like?

Comment: Apparently I need 10 reputation to post images. RDP inbound rule screenshot: http://imgur.com/JoRZOcH. VNC inbound rule screenshot: http://imgur.com/jCLcG2C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem I've seen when defining Azure NSGs. For your inbound Azure NSG rules, the source port needs to be "*" because your client will use a [random port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't believe I didn't realize that.

Comment: I see this all the time. I know to look for it, because I hit the same thing when I first started using the new Azure portal, too. :)